# How to read complicated C++ type declarations when there is no identifier?

Tags: c++, types, syntax

There's the well known spiral and right-left rules etc. for reading complicated C++ types such as

```
int (*(*foo)(char *,double))[9][20];
```

Foo is a pointer (change direction, move out of parentheses)

to a function taking a pointer to char and a double, and returning (change direction again)

a pointer to (parentheses again, change direction)

a 2d-array of dimensions 9,20 of (reached right end, spiral outside to the left)

integers.

But how do I deal with types like this if there is no identifier, such as when defining a function parameter's type:

```
void foo(int *(*(* )(int(* )(int (* )(int))))())
                  ^       ^        ^
                  identifiers omitted
```

How do I identify the innermost element in an intuitive way?
By the way, even the cdecl tool gives a syntax error on this last example, but it does compile.

Surely, the compiler has a well-defined way of parsing gibberish like this. How does it know where to start?

Comment: You read it in the exact same way.  A type doesn't need an identifier to figure out where to start reading from. The parenthesis alone will tell you that.

Comment: Judging by parantheses alone, the 3rd omitted identifier would be the starting point, because there's 5 open unclosed parantheses, but that is incorrect. The first one is the correct one.

Comment: Not a problem when following the spiral pattern. You choose which type you want to know about.  If you want to know what type the 1st `(*)` is, then you spiral from there. If you want to know what type the 2nd `(*)` is, you spiral from there. The type of the 3rd `(*)`? And so on. There is no set rule that says you have to start spiraling from a specific point. You choose where you want to start spiraling from.

Comment: Personally, I start where identifiers _would_ go like you've done. As said, you can build each piece of the declaration and then put them together if you started in the "wrong" spot. You can also do it a bit more systematically with the fact that the C declaration syntax models use (or maybe vice-versa): "I get `void` if I call `foo` with something where I get `int` if I dereference the result of dereferencing the result of dereferencing <missing name> and calling that with something where I get `int` if I dereference <missing name 2> and call that with something where I get `int`  if I ..."

Comment: That said, you're correct in saying compilers have to parse it. I'm not going to say it's more human-friendly, especially when you have the option of breaking the declaration up into aliases for the sake of figuring it out, but there _is_ a fully systematic parsing method.

Comment: When I run into these kinds of hard-to-fathom types, I tease them apart into smaller typedefs (or these days I prefer `using` aliases).  I know that's orthogonal to your question, but that's the process I use to make them more readily understandable.

Comment: Elaborating, the way compilers parse this falls out of the grammar: http://eel.is/c++draft/gram.dcl. However, it's a lot of layers for a human to keep in their head. In digging through layers to figure out the next piece, you'll probably forget the other context you were keeping in your head. I genuinely think the spiral/right-left rule and the decl=use tricks are immensely more useful to humans and the best you're going to get without aliases. However, that example is too many function pointers for me to keep track of at a glance; there's no super duper shortcut for really complex decls.

Comment: I use my IDE's matching parentheses highlighting and start from the left, following the most-vexing parse rule - if it looks like a function declaration, it is a function declaration. You can spiral from outside in just as well as from inside out. And I always `typedef` my function pointer types to prevent this situation from occurring in the first place.

Comment: Handy tool: https://cdecl.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for reading complex types assume that the type has already been parsed (and you know where the "innermost" point is). The rules for parsing work from the outside in, the same as reading complex expressions in math class. When you hit parentheses, give it a name and come back to it (unless it's simple enough to handle on its own). *Disclaimer: I used a text editor to locate matching parentheses. ;)*

The other consideration that comes into play with this declaration is that once a type is a function, the mess in the parameter list is a separate parse. For example, when parsing `void (*)(big old mess)`, you have a pointer to a function. The big old mess is needed for the function's signature but not for understanding that you are dealing with a function.

Moving on to the example at hand:

> ```
> void foo(int *(*(* )(int(* )(int (* )(int))))())
> ```

After reading `void` and `foo`, you hit parentheses with a complex mess inside. Give that mess a name.

```
void foo( A )
```

where `A` is `int *(*(* )(int(* )(int (* )(int))))()`. So your outermost parse is a unary function returning `void`, and we still need to parse the parameter, `A`. *Note that we already know what the overall purpose of this text is: it declares a function named `foo`. The remaining types have no name because names for parameters are optional.*

```
A: int *( B )()
```

where `B` is `*(* )(int(* )(int (* )(int)))`. So the parameter to `foo` is something whose outermost type is a nullary function that returns a pointer to `int`. Presumably we will discover that the "something" is a pointer, but we still need to parse `B` to confirm that. (OK, skip ahead a little and see that `B` starts with an asterisk. It's a pointer to this nullary function.)

```
B: *(* )( C )
```

where `C` is `int(* )(int (* )(int))`. This is a pointer to a unary function whose parameter is some complex type, and whose return value is a pointer to what we parsed previously (the nullary function). As with the initial parse, we have discovered another place to start reading, as the mess has been pushed into the parameter list. The parameter to `foo` is a pointer to a unary function whose parameter is some complex type, and whose return value is a pointer to a nullary function that returns a pointer to `int`.

```
C: int(* )( D )
```

where `D` is `int (* )(int)`. Again, the mess has moved into the parameter list. The thing at this level is a pointer to a unary function that returns an `int`.

```
D: int (* )(int)
```

Finally, simplicity: a pointer to a unary function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`.

So....

This declares `foo` to be a unary function returning `void` whose parameter is a pointer to a unary function, returning a pointer to a nullary function returning a pointer to `int`, whose parameter is a pointer to a unary function returning `int` whose parameter is a pointer to a unary function returning `int` whose parameter is `int`.

The English version is about as comprehensible as the code, no? :) Let's try something more structured.

- `foo`

  - *Returns:* `void`
  - *Parameter:* pointer to a function

    - *Returns:* pointer to a function

      - *Returns:* pointer to `int`
    - *Parameter:* pointer to a function

      - *Returns:* `int`
      - *Parameter:* pointer to a function

        - *Returns:* `int`
        - *Parameter:* `int`

Whew. Don't do this at home, kids. Give your intermediate types names and save the programmers some grief.